# How do I handle Google map markers with info windows if more than 100

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Example http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_maptypecontrols2.htm

Let's say I have 100 markers with info windows. How do I handle it?

Should I list this code for 100 times on my javascript?

```
  var point = new GLatLng(43.91892,-78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window')
  map.addOverlay(marker);

  var point = new GLatLng(43.82589,-79.10040);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window')
  map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array with JSON, which can be generated on the server and loaded asynchronously.

```
{ markers : [
    { lat : 43.91892, lon : -78.89231, html : "Stuff to display" },
    { lat : 43.91892, lon : -78.89231, html : "Stuff to display" },
    { lat : 43.91892, lon : -78.89231, html : "Stuff to display" },
    { lat : 43.91892, lon : -78.89231, html : "Stuff to display" }
  ]
}
```

Then create a function to make you markers:

```
function displayMarker(item){
    var point = new GLatLng(item.lat, item.lon);
    var marker = createMarker(point, item.html);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
}
```

Then loop over your array of items, calling that function every time.